# Look and feel in windows 7 with wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I just begin studying wxWidgets and I have been experimenting it on CODE::BLOCKS. First, I followed with this example http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hworld2.txt. the application does not look so native on windows 7 it looks like my application is running on windows 98. The OK button does not look like it should be, similarly, also wxTextCtrl ( I have try it myself ). What do I miss? Do I have to add some special code or anything else?

Here this is image: http://angsila.cs.buu.ac.th/~52030937/Capture.PNG

Thank you in advanced

Comment: have you looked at using Qt instead, I think wxWidgets is actually out of date.

Comment: Could you suggest some great books about Qt?

Comment: The best book is "C++ GUI Programming with Qt4" by Jasmin Blanchette and Mark Summerfield

Comment: Tony The Lion: great comment. Any substance behind it?

Answer (score 2):

You can add .rc file to your project and include "wx/msw/wx.rc" in it. Then themes should be applied to your GUI (take a look at default samples bundled with wxWidgets - http://screencast.com/t/QTaQqCxO692w).